# Windows boot manager not showing after I install windows xp on separate partition

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot

So normally when you install another OS to a separate partition, you can choose which OS to boot into. For some unknown reason, this is not happening. My computer directly boots into windows xp as if my previous OS wasn't there. How do I get boot manager back?

My previous operating system(s) are windows 8.1 enterprise and windows 7 ultimate.

Comment: Are all the OSs on different partitions on the same hard drive, or is XP on a new separate HD? If it's a separate hard drive, my first guess would be that the boot loader isn't on the first drive it's trying to boot from. From your question though, it sounds like they're all on one.

Comment: They are on different partitions on the same hard drive.

Comment: I'm not sure what it could be off hand then - haven't ever run into that. Sorry I can't help, and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've already reinstalled windows 8.1 enterprise and everything is back to normal, this question can now be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

A) When booted in XP open Disk Management and see which partition is active.

If it is mapped to a drive letter - remember drive letter - lets assume its Z:.

If it is not mapped assign a drive letter, say Z:

See also which drive letter is for Windows 8.1 - assuming its D:

B) Go to administrative command prompt.

**`D:\windows\system32\bootsect /nt60 Z: /force /mbr`**

(if needed change drive letters accordingly to your concrete mappings!)

Now when you reboot you will have the old choice of Windows 8.1 and Windows 7.

Boot to Windows 7.

C) To add Windows XP to boot menu you can use [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net). Download and install.

**Start tool and type function key F9** (or right click and select "Create missing Windows loaders" from pop-up menu) -> this will scan partitions and add Windows XP to boot menu.

On reboot you should have all three choices - 8.1 + 7 + XP